# How to call on view on dyanmic actions in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

Hello friends I am new in zf2. I stuck at one place. In my project I want to to call one view on many action.
My url is "baseurl/g/any-thing-from-from-database" 
I want to call a view on "any-thing-from-from-database" action from another module or same.

My G module have this code on module.config.php

```
 return array(
 'controllers' => array(
     'invokables' => array(
         'G\Controller\G' => 'G\Controller\GController',
     ),
 ),


 'router' => array(
     'routes' => array(
         'g' => array(
             'type'    => 'segment',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/g[/:action][/:id]',
                 'constraints' => array(
                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                 ),
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'G\Controller\G',
                     'action'     => 'g',
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
 ),

 'view_manager' => array(

     'template_path_stack' => array(
         'g' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
     ),
 ),
 );
```

on GController.php

```
         namespace G\Controller;

     use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
     use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
     use Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface as Request;
     use Zend\Stdlib\ResponseInterface as Response;
     use Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer;
     use Students\Form\StudentsForm;
     use Students\Model\Students;


     class GController extends AbstractActionController
            {
                public function dispatch(Request $request, Response $response = null)
                        {
                            $controller = $this->params('controller');
                             $nicname = $this->params('action');
                             if($nicname !== false){

                                 $hosts = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Manager\Model\HostsTable');

                                 if(($data = $hosts->findByNicname($nicname)) !== null){


                                    $captchaService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('SanCaptcha');

                                    $form = new StudentsForm($captchaService);

                                     return array('from'=>$form);
                                 } 
                             }

                                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home',array('controller'=>'application','action'=>'index')); 
                        }


                    public function gAction()
                    {
                        return new ViewModel();
                    }

            }
```

To get different actions from url I have used dispatch function that is working correctly. When i get this action from database I want to show a form with some content from different module named Students or G. But this code only showing header and footer and nothing else without any error.Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think overwriting dispatch method cannot be very good.

I'm sure you don't see anything, because you don't ever render a ViewModel, so no data are there. This is because you disabled default dispatch behaviour and overwrite the action argument in your route. So if you open *http://my.website/g/foobar* then foobarAction() would be called - if your dispatch will work correctly.

So what you could do is simple rename your action param to (for example) foo, take your logic to gAction() and do what ever you have to do with *$this->param('foo')*.

Comment: thanks for your reply , but how to enable default dispatch behavior

Comment: I meant to not overwrite the dispatch method.